# Why is this implementaion of Lucene not returning any results?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm adding SimpleLuucene to my app which is a wrapper layer that makes Lucene simpler to implement in basic situations, hoping to improve query speed.  However when I did the most simplistic working concept to wire up the code I do not get any results.  What am I doing wrong?

*PS:* I left out the code to initially create my indexes. But it has been run and the cfs and fdt files have data.

```
var searchcriteria = new Search.Helpers.Mapping().MapToModel(postdata);
var searcher = new DirectoryIndexSearcher(
    new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\search.index"), 
    true);
var query = new TermQuery(
    new Term("situs", "1144 Air Cargo Ave, Sarasota, Fl, 34243"));

var searchService = new SearchService(searcher);
var luceneresults = searchService.SearchIndex(query);
```

Comment: What are you trying to match: docs with the exact phrase "1144 Air Cargo...", docs containing all of those words in any order, or docs containing any of those words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query object `TermQuery` will try to match the input value *exactly* as is. Any difference between input and indexed values (such as `Fl` instead of `FL`) will result in zero match. All casing, spaces and symbols need to be identical for Lucene to return a matching document. I would suggest pre-processing the input and indexed value before hand (i.e. lower-casing strings before indexing, and similarly for all search input) to avoid the subtle differences.